# How to make a Ruby tool get the Z coordinate of a user selected point on SketchUp?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm writing a tool/command menu, and I would like to let the user pick a point so I can get the Z coordinate to draw further entities.

Reading http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/inputpoint#positionand http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/tool#onLButtonDoubleClick I wrote this:

```
#use this inside a tool script/menu command added to the UI
def onLButtonDoubleClick(flags, x, y, view)
 ip1 = view.inputpoint x,y
 pz = ip1.position.z
end
```

Kind of works, but feels ugly. How to give the user some snap/inferences feedback? Can some expert person show a nicer way to do it?

Comment: Any clarification to why it only kind of works? It's not clear to me what the issue is.

InputPoint gives you inference picking - like when you use the Line tool etc and you see the little dot snapping. PickHelper simply return a list of possible entities that would be hit given a X,Y coordinate - like a single click using the Select tool. No inference.

Comment: Hi thomthom! I'm not sure this code I used uses inferences, I think it doesn't...

Comment: Can you explain more what you try to achieve? I see you using InputPoint in the double-click event - but I don't understand what the expected results are nor what actual results you see are.

Inference is often used along with mouse events - picking duing the mouse move. The InputPoint will inference based on it's data points.

But without knowing more about what you try to do it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: Thanks for the patience! I think this is OK for now.I was looking for a nice way of letting the user select a point in the model so I can use the Z coordinate of the point to create some geometry. A single click would do.